# How to create a new plug-in to Theia or Che-theia IDE?

Tags: eclipse-che, theia

How to create plug-in (not extension) for Che-theia (Theia integrated in Che) or Theia standalone ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the yeoman generator as describe here: https://www.theia-ide.org/doc/Authoring_Plugins.html